# Use of Undeclared Identifier 'calculateAge'

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective and just trying to understand simple concepts. 
I have read Objective C for dummies and Cocoa Programming for Mac OSX (most of it). 
I tried to make a simple small program on my own and realized I know very little.

I keep getting the `"Use of Undeclared Identifier "calculateAge', did you mean 'Calculate' "` error.

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code below and why?
Thanks a bunch in advance.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Calculate : NSObject
{
    int myYear;
    int nowYear;
}


- (int) calculateAge:(int)birthYear:(int)nowYear;

@end



@implementation Calculate



- (int) calculateAge:(int)birthYear:(int)nowYear// need myYear
{

    NSLog(@"The birthYear is: %i\n", birthYear);
    int myAge = nowYear - birthYear;        
    //NSLog(@"The nowYear is: %i\n", nowYear);
    NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);
    return myAge;
}



int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {


        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        int myY = 1963;
        int nowY = 2012;
        int myYear = 1963;
        int nowYear = 2012;
        //int myAge = calculateAge:(int) birthYear: (int) nowYear;
        int myAge = calculateAge:(int) myY: (int) nowY;
        NSLog(@"The nowYear is: %i\n", nowYear);
        NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);

    }
    return 0;
}
@end
```

Comment: what **exactly** does the compiler say? (the error, I mean).

Comment: Don't you need to send the calculateAge signal to an instance of your Calculate class?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be conflating the method name with the parameter list. A proper signature would look something like this:

```
- (int)calculateAgeFromBirthYear:(int)birthYear currentYear:(int)currentYear
```

This could then be implemented like this:

```
- (int)calculateAgeFromBirthYear:(int)birthYear currentYear:(int)currentYear
{

    NSLog(@"The birthYear is: %i\n", birthYear);
    int myAge = currentYear - birthYear;        
    //NSLog(@"The nowYear is: %i\n", currentYear);
    NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);
    return myAge;
}
```

This could then be called like this:

```
Calculate *calculator = [[Calculate  alloc] init];
int myAge = [calculator calculateAgeFromBirthYear:myY currentYear:nowY];
```

Don't implement `main` inside a class implementation; it belongs outside in the global namespace, preferably in its own file.

Comment: Dead on Warrenm, it seems I am rather confused on where to put what and why.  Your fixes did the trick.  I guess it's time to continue reading.   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare the instance variables in the interface.
The last `@end` needs to be before the main function, it is not part of the class, it used the class.
The `Calculate` class needs to be instantiated and the call needs to be made to the instantiated class.
The `calculateAge...` method should be renamed to indicate each argument.
Variables should be given full names, abreviations generall end up making things less clear.

Here is an example:

```
@interface Calculate : NSObject
- (int) calculateAgeWithBirthYear:(int)birthYear nowYear:(int)nowYear;
@end

@implementation Calculate
- (int) calculateAgeWithBirthYear:(int)birthYear nowYear:(int)nowYear// need myYear
{
    NSLog(@"The birthYear is: %i\n", birthYear);
    int myAge = nowYear - birthYear;
    NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);
    return myAge;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        int myBirthYear = 1963;
        int nowYear = 2012;

        Calculate *calculator = [[Calculate alloc] init];
        int myAge = [calculator calculateAgeWithBirthYear:myBirthYear nowYear:nowYear];

        NSLog(@"The nowYear is: %i\n", nowYear);
        NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

NSLog output:

Hello, World!
The birthYear is: 1963
The age is: 49
The nowYear is: 2012
The age is: 49

Using instance variables created by `@property~ statements:

```
@interface Calculate : NSObject
@property int myYear;
@property int nowYear;

- (int) calculateAge;
@end

@implementation Calculate
- (int) calculateAge // need myYear
{
    NSLog(@"The birthYear is: %i\n", self.myYear);
    int myAge = self.nowYear - self.myYear;
    NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);
    return myAge;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        Calculate *calculator = [[Calculate alloc] init];
        calculator.myYear = 1963;
        calculator.nowYear = 2012;

        int myAge = [calculator calculateAge];

        NSLog(@"The nowYear is: %i\n", calculator.nowYear);
        NSLog(@"The age is: %i\n", myAge);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The instance variables in the interface was originally put becouse as I evolve my simple program I will have the variables brought in from user input.  User will enter birth year, I will get the current year from the computer and then calculate the age.  All in good time, I am rather slow but wanted to see something on the screen.   Thanks

Comment: In that case use them instead of passing the value in.